# Capture with single quotes In triple quoted string

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose this regexp in Javascript:

```
/(?:"""([\s\S]*?)""")/g
```

How could I make it, so that both of the following captures work?

```
"""foo"""
```

to capture:

```
foo
```

but also...

```
"""foo "bar baz""""
```

to capture:

```
foo "bar baz"
```

?

**Note:** Atm I wouldn't know how to capture the second example.

Put differently, I need to make sure that the final quote in what I want to capture does not break the triple quote pattern, i.e. match the first three triple quotes only rather than the last three.

Comment: what's the expected result

Comment: show some complex input and the final output

Comment: I think I gave two examples, the second one is the one I am unable to produce ...so I added a note at the bottom of the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match up to the last `"` in the substring.

```
/"""([\s\S]*?)"""(?!")/g
```

```js
var str = '"""foo""" """foo "bar baz""""';

var regex = /"""([\s\S]*?)"""(?!")/g;
var m;

while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/K1ns41/3)

Comment: appears to work ,thx ...will read some more on negative lookaheads

Comment: Hi @Pranav, thanks for helping me resolve this parsing problem.

If you want to see the fruits of your help, take a look at:

https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5/pull/2736

Comment: @tobibeer : glad to help :)